# Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Identifier found in modules annotations-12.0 and annotations-23.0 Error While Running Android App

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

Gradle build tasks succeeds but on running the android app the build fails with the error logs below

```
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Identifier found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$AdjustableOrientation found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$BoxLayoutAxis found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CalendarMonth found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CursorType found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FlowLayoutAlignment found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FontStyle found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$HorizontalAlignment found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$InputEventMask found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$ListSelectionMode found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$PatternFlags found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TabLayoutPolicy found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TabPlacement found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TitledBorderJustification found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TitledBorderTitlePosition found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TreeSelectionMode found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.MagicConstant found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Pattern found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.PrintFormat found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.PrintFormatPattern found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.RegExp found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Subst found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Nls found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.NonNls found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.PropertyKey found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.TestOnly found in modules annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and annotations-23.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0)
```

Checking for the duplicates,
at first I tried this [gradle-dependency checker lib](https://github.com/cjstehno/dependency-checker)  but it didn't offer more details about the duplicate location.

I also tried listing all my dependencies with gradle project:dependencies >> gradleDuplicates.log

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by a transitive dependency conflict between the room compiler(v2.6.0) and compose accompanist pager(v0.30.0) library.

Room compiler uses `com.intellij:annotations:12.0` while accompanist pager uses `org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0` as a transitive dependency.

The solution is to exclude one of the depdencies, I exluded Room's transitive dependency

```
configurations.implementation{
    exclude(group = "com.intellij", module = "annotations")
}
```